# Rails produces invalid SQL for count on complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a repost from https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22491

Given this statement:

```
@items = DailyList.joins(:bar)
                              .select("daily_lists.*, (point(12, 34) <@> bars.coords) as bar_distance")
                              .order("bar_distance ASC")
                              .group('bars.id, daily_lists.id')
                              .limit(3)
```

it produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT  daily_lists.*, (point(12, 34) <@> bars.coords) bar_distance
FROM "daily_lists"
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."id" = "daily_lists"."bar_id"
GROUP BY bars.id, daily_lists.id 
ORDER BY bar_distance ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Now we want to check how much records we've got, **@items.count**:

```
SELECT  COUNT(daily_lists.*, (point(12, 34) <@> bars.coords) as bar_distance) AS count_daily_lists_all_point_12_34_bars_coords_as_bar_distance, bars.id, daily_lists.id AS bars_id_daily_lists_id
FROM "daily_lists"
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."id" = "daily_lists"."bar_id"
GROUP BY bars.id, daily_lists.id 
ORDER BY bar_distance ASC
LIMIT 3

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 1: ...NT(daily_lists.*, (point(12, 34) <@> bars.coords) as bar_dis...
```

Now I'm trying to use :all as a workaround, **@items.count(:all)**:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS count_all, bars.id, daily_lists.id AS bars_id_daily_lists_id
FROM "daily_lists"
INNER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."id" = "daily_lists"."bar_id"
GROUP BY bars.id, daily_lists.id 
ORDER BY bar_distance ASC
LIMIT 3

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "bar_distance" does not exist
```

Guys... what to do?

Comment: Report it as a bug on Rail's github

Answer (score 0):

The "as bar_distance" is the problem, I think. You cannot alias within a count.

```
@items = DailyList.joins(:bar)
                  .select("daily_lists.*, (point(12, 34) <@> bars.coords) as bar_distance")
                  .order("bar_distance ASC")
                  .group('bars.id, daily_lists.id')
                  .limit(3)

@item_count = DailyList.joins(:bar)
                       .select("daily_lists.*, (point(12, 34) <@> bars.coords)")
                       .group('bars.id, daily_lists.id')
                       .limit(3)
                       .count
```

Comment: problem is that it's not me. it's rails

Comment: The syntax that Arel builds is correct for the the first pass of the query. But it can't anticipate that the syntax provided to the .select method, while normally correct, becomes invalid when you append the .count method. You're going to have to have two queries: one that groups and sorts and another that counts. I don't see another way. My original answer is edited with an example.